# Why does the pragma order matter when enabling experimental features?

Tags: perl, pragma

Is it the defined behavior that the order of `features` and `use version` matters?

```
use feature 'signatures';
use v5.026;
```

vs

```
use v5.026;
use feature 'signatures';
```

The top will produce an error,

> Global symbol requires explicit package name

on

```
use feature 'signatures';                                                                                        
use v5.026;                                                                                                      

sub foo ($opt1, $opt2 = undef) {                                                                                 
  say $opt1 if $opt2;                                                                                            
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `use v5.026` declaration [implicitly enables](https://perldoc.pl/functions/use) the [feature bundle](https://perldoc.pl/feature#FEATURE-BUNDLES) for that version, in this case it would be equivalent to `no feature ':all'; use feature ':5.26'`. This overrides the features you had enabled/disabled already.

Comment: Clearly, I can't figure out what the logic is in having it disable features explicitly enabled.

Comment: This is actually [documented under the feature pragma as well](https://perldoc.pl/feature#IMPLICIT-LOADING) - it will first disable all features. I suspect this is because the `array_base` feature is default, but has been removed from all bundles since `:5.16`.

Comment: I don't see it documented on that link. It mentions enabling features, not disabling enabled features. You'd have to read enabled in such a way that the two were the same.

Comment: @EvanCarroll `no feature ':all';` disables all features. That's what I was referring to.

Comment: I guess the `array_base` piece is interesting. I see features as being a method of **adding** functionality to perl, that it's being used to remove functionality was just weird at first but it's all good.

Comment: Funny enough, `array_base` will be moot starting with 5.30 because actually making use of that feature will be a [fatal error](https://perldoc.pl/5.29.7/variables/$%5B).

Comment: @Evan Carroll, Re "*Clearly, I can't figure out what the logic is in having it disable features explicitly enabled.*", Because `use v5.x;` doesn't mean you want the features from 5.x, it means you want the language 5.x. This includes both turning on features that were in 5.x, and turning off features that weren't. Use `use feature ':5.x';` if you just want to turn on features.